# My final mix sounds damp

Tags: mixing, headphones, ableton, master

My final mix, mastered amateurly by me, sounds damp when I play it at low volume in my Bose QC 35 II headphone.
It feels like it is sitting really deep in the headphone; i'm comparing it pro songs at same volume.
But turning up the volume makes it competitive.

I've done everything all mixing/mastering on Sennheiser HD206.
on Ableton.

hELP PLEASE!

Comment: Basically what I mean is my song feels too much inside the speakers, especially at low volume. But pro songs at the same volume feel more lively and balanced in the speakers.

Comment: Please look at our posts on here about mastering and equalisation. Look also at the concept of stereo image. This is all covered in posts here already.